# How to get around $scope dependency in AngularJS services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a set of services for a developers to use that hides some of the boilerplate code for (say) putting focus on a field.  How to I get around injecting $scope into these services when the implementation requires access to it?

For example:

```
var focus = function ($scope, $timeout) {
        return function (name) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast('focusOn', name);
            });
        };
    };
```

Comment: You should not be doing this. Try and rethink the code so that you don't need to use `$broadcast`. You can also inject `$rootScope` in a service, but again, you can probably refactor the code so that you don't need to `$broadcast`.

Comment: Precisely. I understand I need to refactor, but I am looking for a small sample that demonstrates this.

Comment: if you need to access $scope of some <yourElement> - you just can call `var $scope = angular.element(<yourElement>).scope()`